Converting Text Field to Numeric in Tableau
I've been trying to convert a text field ($amount) into a numeric field. However, I keep running into an "Oracle database error 1722: ORA-01722: invalid number." Does anyone know why this might be happening?
This is what I've tried:
ZN(FLOAT(
    IF [Amounts] = "-" THEN NULL
    ELSE [Amounts]
    END
))


This question is similar to: SQL error "ORA-01722: invalid number". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
